# How to send Bitcoin > $1 on Coinbase?

Tags: coinbase-api

When I tried to send $1 equivalent of Bitcoin using the Coinbase API I get this error:

```
ClientError [ValidationError]: Amount is below the minimum (0.0001 BTC) required to send on-blockchain.
```

How is it possible to enable microtransactions with Bitcoin? I want users to be able to trade in game items under 1 dollar (Coinbase's daily limit per user). I understand this restriction is due to transaction fees, but I know apps exist like Bitcoin Blast, where users are regularly awarded miniscule amounts of Bitcoin.

How do you think they do it? What could be a solution for using microtransactions with Coinbase API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of those apps would tell the users they have earned Bitcoin but require the user to have x amount of Bitcoin before being able to withdraw, with the threshold above the 0.0001 BTC minimum transaction requirement.

I think Robinhood does something similar where you can buy $1 of BTC on Robinhood but you don't have access to the crypto's wallet address. This is because Robinhood owns all your crypto and you're just trading the spot price. They made a large investment in crypto awhile ago and they hold that as collateral allowing users to buy and sell BTC for $1 without paying transaction fees because users are not trading BTC on the blockchain, they are trading Robinhood's supply of crypto.

You could do something similar as well, people can spend $1 worth of BTC on a game item but they're just trading the spot price of BTC and the transaction takes place in your game's digital ledger rather than Bitcoins' blockchain.

If you want your users to withdraw crypto, someone is going to have to pay that fee. You can either pay the fee yourself, have the user pay the fee, or do something like Robinhood where you can only deposit/withdraw in cash but users can exchange that cash for crypto that they don't get wallet access to.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I will try cryptos with lower transaction fees like Litecoin. I had talked to the VP of Software Engineering at Bling for my job application and he alluded to an agreement between Coinbase and Bling, on introducing more new users in exchange for microtransactions. I did not press further which is why I'm looking for more information.

Comment: Oh cool that makes sense too, I had a feeling there was a special contract going on with larger companies but it was just a hunch, I haven't seen any proof before you said so. I think if you get a lot of users on your game you can contact Coinbase for a similar deal